# Aggregatin Fields vs. Aggregation Functions for constants

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Faced the following dilema:
Is it better (performence-wize) to add feilds that have constant number value as a group by feild or to add aggfunc that will return the same number ?

For example, my table:

```
User   NUM    VALUE    ...
1       5       1
2       7       2
3       9       3
1       5       4
2       7       5
3       9       6
```

So is it better to use:

```
Select user, avg(number),...
From table
Group by user
```

OR

```
Select user, number, ...
From table
Group by user, number
```

Using Google BigQuery if relevant.
The desired reault is the best oerforemnce in one of the above ways.

Thanks !!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the difference in performance.  However, you could test it to see if one or the other works better on your data.

Comment: It really depends on many factors. Without knowing context of your use case - you will most likely get useless or even incorrect answers that will really be hard to validate as such and will mislead you to wrong direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the use of aggregation function may vary with the complexity of your query, size of your data and the desired output. BigQuery counts with [Approximate Aggregate Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#approximate_aggregate_functions), which are scalable and therefore faster but the output is an approximation. Thus, you rely on your case of use. Moreover, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute), there are predefined best practices which will increase your general query performance in BigQuery.

Below are some of best practices to be followed:

[1)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#control_projection_-_avoid_select_) Avoid Select * : control the number of columns read by your query.

[2)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#prune_partitioned_queries) Use filters such as where or prune partitioned tables selecting a time window.

[3)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-communication#reduce_data_before_using_a_join) Reduce the data before using JOIN.
3)

Following the best practices exemplified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview) will increase your query performance. As well as, choosing the best way to filter, aggregate and join your data specifically to your case.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of performance, the less amount of work for the engine is better. In this case, the first query would be less resource intensive than the second one.

As a side note, using less columns opens the possibility of using a wider range of indexes, if these are present. The optimizer may be able to pick a better index since it's less constrained.

Comment: Thanks, so is there a preferd function? Min/max/avg?

Comment: Computing aggregation functions such as `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()` does not make a difference. Their performance is pretty much the same.